# Reporting OGC services data?

Tags: web-service, metadata, reports, ows

I have been asked to create some sort of reporting of OGC services data, and as well some sort of comparison reports to show comparison.  I have not worked much with OGC services, but in review I felt the WMS GetCapabilities would be the easiest to extract.

To start moving on the project, I parsed the XML to a flat file and created a database, easy enough, but as I look I see there must be a better way.  I have several thousand endpoints to review and need to look at the entire request with time.  What tools are available to assist in querying service request, as I learn this product?

Comment: Are you using something like GeoServer?

Comment: what sort of report do you need? is it about the layers available or usage of the layer?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you need to set up a catalogue, for example you could use [GeoNetwork](http://geonetwork-opensource.org/)

You can load metadata into the catalogue and can have a visual comparison through the records, or you can create your own queries against the database of metadata using [CSW](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/cat)